# Android EditText have always padding from bottom

Tags: android, android-edittext

This is my ListView XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+list/list_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/defaultbg"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+list/filter_button"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/SmallLogo"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/filter" />

    <!-- empty view -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+list/empty"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/defaultbg"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/whos_around_empty_text"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+list/filter"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:hint="@string/search"                
        android:visibility="visible"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The EditText is at the bottom of the view but from some reason it is not tight to the bottom..

When examine it carefully I've seen that the layout is right on bottom - but the inside white background doesn't cover the whole layout (kind of like when the ImageView size is bigger then the layout size and you use scaleType)..

It is really important to me that the EditText will be tight to the bottom... any ideas ??

**UPDATE: Adding screen shot:**

[image: screenShot]

As you can see - the bottom of the editText white background is not aligned down to the bottom of the screen... although the layout itself is aligned

Comment: android:layout_below="@+id/list_view"

Comment: that doesn't work... it disappear.

Comment: btw - when aligning it to top - it works good

Comment: You can try setting bottom margin to 0 using android:layout_marginBottom="0dip"

Comment: as i said - the layout is tight down... the problem is that inside the layout there is some sort of padding with the background color.. i will add pic to the question

Comment: I am not sure about the exact issue but you have the listview in the same layout as other views and heigh set to wrap_content, which is never a good idea because then it can grow and push things around.  What happens when you remove the listview all together?

Comment: the EditText stays in his exact position - because its a relative layout and the alignment is being made relatively to the parent... the alignment of the EditText has nothing to do with the ListView or EmptyTextView in a relative layout - as long as the EditText doesn't align according to them

Comment: Hello @AsafNevo ! Did you find a solution? I met the same issue with a  class extending EditText ! It's amazing that there is so little concern about it: the EditText is not centered by nature :(
There really is a bottom built-in padding that is quite annoying.
I solved my issue by adding some equivalent margin under my adjacent button because I did not need  to strictly stuck it to the bottom of the enclosing frame.

Comment: @Poutrathor thanks for you solution.. i must say i don't really remember :) its an old project, but i guess i solved it some how.
When reading the posts here, i would have consider changing the background drawable of the EditText to an new XML drawable with no padding. my guess is that the default background drawable of the EditText has some padding..

Answer (score 5):

In Android, all widgets have some padding and margin from other views for better visibility.
Every widget have 4 dp margin and 8 dp padding. If you don't want that you can create a custom view.

For now, Try margin at the bottom with negative pixels.

```
android:layout_marginBottom="-4dp"
```

worked fine on my layout

Comment: thanks for your answer. First, as you can see in my screenshot the problem is not with margin. it might be padding. Second, I've tried to change it to android:paddingBottom="-8dp" but nothing happned

Comment: @Asaf Nevo  I am not saying to set padding to -8dp, I am telling to set margin. Take a look at the code Mr.

Comment: I did tried it and it changes nothing...
may it has something to do with the layout_alignParentBottom="true"?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I have done like that screen.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/empty"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"

    android:text="@string/whos_around_empty_text"
    android:background="@drawable/defaultbg"
    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@id/relative"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+list/filter_button"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:contentDescription="Smalllogo"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/filter" />

    <!-- empty view -->

    <EditText
        android:id="@+list/filter"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:hint="Search"
        android:visibility="visible" />
</RelativeLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/defaultbg"
    android:layout_above="@id/relative"
    android:layout_below="@id/empty"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" />
```

Comment: Please mention what sort of change you made?

Comment: it does work as you mentioned but i wanted the ImageButton and the EditText to float over the ListView or EmptyTextView.. not to be under it

Comment: suppose `ListView` didn't have any item means `EditText` should appear in bottom.

Comment: it does appear, but your code - as seen in your screen shot - is locating my edittext under the current view (ListView or EmptyTextView).. i want it to float over it